# ConfigurationManager.ConnectionString reads app.config from different location

Tags: c#, winforms, connection-string

The app.config of my C# windows application has the following ConnectionString

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="DS1" connectionString="Data Source=DataSource1;" providerName="" />
    <add name="DS2" connectionString="Data Source=DataSource2;" providerName="" />
    <add name="DS3" connectionString="Data Source=DataSource3;" providerName="" />
    <add name="DS4" connectionString="Data Source=DataSource4;" providerName="" />
</connectionStrings>
```

After installing the setup, the same connection strings exist in the projectname.config of installation directory C:\ProgramFiles\ProjectName\ProjectName.config.

When i run the application, i have the following code to access the connection string

```
foreach (ConnectionStringSettings key in ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings)
        {
            Display ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[key.Name].Name,

        }
```

The Key names are not displaying as DS1, DS2, DS3 and DS4 .

Instead it is reading the ProjectName.config file present in

```
C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\VirtualStore\Program Files\ProjectName\ProjectName.exe.config
```

This was saved long back when project was installed but when uninstalled it doesn't get removed.

How can i make changes in C# to read the proper ProjectName.config file from installation dircectory and not from AppData folders.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 string theConfigFileName ="FilePath";
 ExeConfigurationFileMap userConfigFileMap = new ExeConfigurationFileMap() { ExeConfigFilename = theConfigFileName };
 Configuration userConfig = ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedExeConfiguration(userConfigFileMap, ConfigurationUserLevel.None);

foreach (var item in userConfig.ConnectionStrings.ConnectionStrings)
{

}
```

Comment: is there a way i can delete app.config stored in appdata when i uninstall the application ?

Comment: using add or remove programs in control panel.Reference to 3rd party software to remove app.config from APPDATA is not acceptable :)

Comment: Add an installer class to your project.
Check the link on Tom Studee's answer

Comment: i have setup deployment project created in project solution. I build it and it will give me projectname.setup.msi. I double click and install it

Answer (score 0):

On app startup you could check for the existence of the original config and delete it.

```
string originalConfig = string.Format("C:\Users\{0}\AppData\Local\VirtualStore\Program Files\ProjectName\ProjectName.exe.config", Environment.UserName);

if (System.IO.File.Exists(originalConfig))
{
    System.IO.File.Delete(originalConfig);
}
```

If you wanted to do it during the uninstall, you could execute this code in a custom action:

```
System.IO.Directory.Delete("%APPDATA%\ProjectName");
```

See msdn for [creating a custom action](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/d9k65z2d(v=vs.100).aspx)

Comment: is there a way i can delete app.config stored in appdata when i uninstall the application ?

Comment: Hardcoding the path may not be a good idea because each system may have unique paths ( based on OS )

Comment: Right, and one way to handle that would be to test for the existence of a file in each possible path. Another would be to test for the OS version.